# Console disappears on markdown

Tags: html, r, markdown, rstudio

I'm having a problem because I'm trying to do a markdown (HTML) in R and everytime that I run it, the console where you input the code just disappears and transforms into the picture below.

Any ideas what is happening? This never happened to me before and I already did several markdowns in this computer.

[image]

Comment: As far as I can see the console is still there (bottom left window..). What do you exactly mean by the console is not there anymore?

Comment: Sorry I explained it wrong. What I meant is that the source code goes little bit crazy. But I figured it out, just does that whenever I save the html with the same name of other markdown and replace it. If I save the markdown html with a new name doesn't do it.